# Intermittent DNS failures after upgrading to Snow Leopard

Tags: macos, networking, osx-snow-leopard, dns

After a fairly painless upgrade from Tiger to Snow Leopard, I was able to download a few things.  Then I started having difficulty connecting to multiple sites.  Network service would come back from time to time.  I eventually figured out that some sites would work because they were dns-cached, while new sites were failing at the DNS lookup.  I have another computer on the same LAN, so I know it's not an upstream problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DNS server behavior changed in Snow Leopard.  I had a custom network location set up with an additional DNS server (my router, so I can use network names for my two computers)  In 10.4/Tiger, this server was queried **in addition to** the DHCP servers.  in 10.6 Snow Leopard, it is queried **instead of** the DHCP servers.  I had no trouble when switching back to the `Automatic` location, or writing down the DHCP servers and entering them manually (partially voiding the point of DHCP)